# Is is ok to use credit spreads to account for a drop in time series for vector error correction model?

Tags: cointegration

I am doing a time series analysis on a quarterly basis from 1990 to the third quarter 2012. Some of the time series had a drop in 2008 because of recession then resumed upwards. This drop is rather steep.  I am thinking of using credit spreads since credit spreads follows the economy rather well.  Then I can apply cointegration and VECM on the series.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site! Providing a bit more information about the approach you're imagining might help you get an answer that you can use! Maybe tell us a bit about the structure of your data and show a graph depicting the drop you describe?